# Show simple continued fraction with Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: proof-writing, continued-fractions, euclidean-algorithm

I have this math problem, I have to show a simple continued fraction from equations. Here's the question.

> Use these equations: $$397 = 204(1) + 193$$$$204 = 193(1) + 11$$$$193
>  = 11(17) + 6$$$$11 = 6(1) + 5$$$$6 = 5(1) + 1$$$$5 = 1(5)$$ to show that: $$\frac{397}{204}=1+\frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{17+\frac{1}{1 +
>  \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{5}}}}}$$

I'm not completely sure where to start or how to attempt this problem. I see a pattern in the fraction of $5,1,1,17,1,1$. Which are the numbers in the parenthesis backwards... but I'm still stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Start at the top.  $397/204 = 1 + 193/204$.  Now the latter part is less than one, so consider its reciprocal:  $193/204 = 1/(204/193)$.  Proceed to rewrite $204/193$ just as we did at the top, i.e. $204/193 = 1 + 11/193$.  Continue until the indicated division is exact, which is inevitable since the denominators are decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every (positive) real number has a simple continued fraction expansion, one which terminates if and only if the number is rational.  Let's start with how one expands $x \gt 0$ in a simple continued fraction, and then reflect on the special case where $x = a/b$ is rational.

First off, we take the [integer part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$:

$$ x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\} $$

Note that the curly braces here denote the fractional part, $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, and that for clarity we are dealing only with nonnegative parts.

The simple continued fraction expansion proceeds (unless $\{x\}$ is zero, in which case we stop) by taking the reciprocal of $\{x\}$.  Since the nonzero fractional part is strictly between $0$ and $1$, its reciprocal is strictly greater than $1$:

$$ y = \frac{1}{\{x\}} $$

$$ x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \frac{1}{y} $$

As we repeat these two steps, breaking $y$ into integer and fractional parts and reciprocating the fractional part if nonzero, we develop the nested expression that is [the simple continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $x$:

$$ x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \frac{1}{ \lfloor y \rfloor + \frac{1}{\ddots} } $$

It should be evident that the process terminates precisely on rational numbers $x$.  [Another interesting fact is that positive roots of integer quadratic equations have simple continued fraction expansions that are eventually periodic/repeating, and conversely.  But this is a tangent, to explore another day.]

Moreover one finds that applying the above procedure to rational $x = a/b$ is just like the division and remainder steps of Euclid's algorithm for the GCD of $a$ and $b$.  That is, if $a = qb + r$ with $0 \le r \lt b$ in positive integers, then:

$$ \frac{a}{b} = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\{ \frac{a}{b} \right\} = q + \frac{r}{b} = q + \frac{1}{ (b/r) } $$

Then we proceed as before with $y = b/r$.  Since $r \lt b$, it is now rigorous that the process terminates in a finite number of steps (eventually reaching a zero remainder in the division algorithm step).

The Question here shows the work for the process applied to $x = \frac{397}{204}$, with the quotients of the division algorithm steps shown in parentheses.